# How to do a left join in Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, join

I'm new to Entity Framework and I have some troubles with a query that includes a join.
Here's the model I'm using:
http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/7132/modelow.png

I want to query all models, with the enabled info for a given profile (which I get from the instance info).
As first step I'm trying to get all models with the enabled info when it exists (left join), but that fails. I tried the Join method but I can't even get to compile.

```
var modelList = dc.db.models.Join(dc.db.profile_model,
                y => y.id,
                s => s.models.id,
                (y, s) => new Object( y.id, y.display, s.enabled, s.models, s.profiles )
                ))
```

MSDN about this function does not correspond to what intellisense gives me, and I have troubles with the parameters. I think the first 3 ones are ok (2nd table and the 2 keys on which to join), but I can't get the last one correctly. How am I supposed to get an object that contains all fields of both models and profile_model?

Thanks

---

**Update:**
To be clearer, here's the query as written in plain good old SQL:

```
select m.*, p.enabled from models m
left join profile_model p on m.id = p.model_id
where p.profile_id = 
(
  select profile_id from instances where instances.display = 'PTXM11602' 
)
or profile_id is null
```

How would it be written using e-f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a list of models with per model all instances of that model. When you designed your model correctly and have all correct referential keys in the database, you should be able to write something like this:

```
var models =
    from model in db.models
    where (
        from pm in model.profile_models
        from instance in pm.profile.instances
        where instance.display == "PTXM11602").Any()
      ||
        !model.profile_models.Any()
    select model;

var results =
    from pm in db.profile_models
    where pm.profile.instances.Any(i => i.display == "PTXM11602")
    where models.Contains(pm.model)
    select new 
    {
        Model = pm.model,
        Enabled = pm.enabled
    };
```

Please read [this MSDN forum](http://bit.ly/vOsbL) to get the `Contains` method to work with Entity Framework 3.5.

Comment: Not exactly. I want the list of all models, and if that relationship exists, the info about the association with a given instance through a profile.

Comment: I'm not sure what "the info about the association with a given instance through a profile" means. Can you explain?

Comment: Models are associated with a profile (n to m relationship). For each relation, there is additional info stored in the profile_model table, like "enabled" (association between a model and a profile exists, but can bet turned on/off, indicated by the "enabled" field).

Comment: Okay... so what would you like to be the actual result of the query: which columns do you like? 100% sure you can do this with LINQ in an easy way, but still not sure I get it.

Comment: the results I want are model ID & display, and the enabled field where it exists.

Comment: @Antoine: See my update. The trick is that with LINQ, you never need to do an OUTER JOIN. The provider will decide to do this based on your model's metadata. Do you see how much simpler those queries become in LINQ. However, it does take some time to train your mind in this new model.

Comment: Thanks Steven, but there's still a flaw. Your query works, but selects only models that are associated with a profile. I would need this query to also return models that are not associated with a profile, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Antoine: Ha yes, I see. I updated my answer. That should do the trick. `DefaultIfEmpty` effectively acts as an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Seems it doesn't like the DefaultIfEmpty, it keeps sending me a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MetricsAdm.profile_model] DefaultIfEmpty[profile_model]
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MetricsAdm.profile_model])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."  
I've tried to play with the query to change anything, but only removing the DefaultIfEmpty makes it work.

Comment: @Antoine: That's a bummer. You are using EF 3.5. The LINQ provider of EF 3.5 really stinks. I updated my answer again. Perhaps this will work in EF 3.5, but it will possibly fail on the `Contain` method. After that I'm out of tricks. Make your life easier and migrate to .NET 4.0.

Comment: You're right, that fails on the Contains() method. I'll update and try again. Thx.

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN forum. There is a solution for working with contains in EF 3.5: http://bit.ly/vOsbL.

Comment: Migrated to .net 4.0 and your previous query works just fine. Thx a lot for your effort!